# 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame' error while using 'iloc'

Tags: python, pandas

Jupiter nootbook is returning this warning:

```
*C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:337: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:517: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
self.obj[item] = s*
```

After runing the following code:

```
def group_df(df,num):
    ln = len(df)
    rang = np.arange(ln)
    splt = np.array_split(rang,num)
    lst = []
    finel_lst = []
    for i,x in enumerate(splt):
        lst.append([i for x in range(len(x))])
    for k in lst:
        for j in k:
            finel_lst.append(j)
    df['group'] = finel_lst
    return df
def KNN(dafra,folds,K,fi,target):        
    df = group_df(dafra,folds)
    avarge_e = []
    for i in range(folds):
        train = df.loc[df['group'] != i]
        test = df.loc[df['group'] == i]
        test.loc[:,'pred_price'] = np.nan
        test.loc[:,'rmse'] = np.nan
        print(test.columns)
KNN(data,5,5,'GrLivArea','SalePrice')
```

In the error message, it is recommended to use `.loc` indexing- which i did, but it did not help. Please help me- what is the problem ? I have went through the related questions and read the documentation, but i still don't get it.

Comment: Does it say in which line the warning occurs and what was your previous version?

Comment: edited to inculde the whole warning

Comment: Since the question is already answered, just a small thing. You can replace you `group_df` method with this one `df['groups'] = pd.qcut(range(len(df)), folds, labels=False, retbins=True)[0]` It's a built-in function from pandas which is supposed to create equal sized bins. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
train = df.loc[df['group'] != i].copy()
test = df.loc[df['group'] == i].copy()
```

If you modify values in `test` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. please, explain to me what was the problem and how your proposal fixed it ? :)

Comment: Yes, give me a sec.

Comment: so, loc indexing creates a 'view' into the original df, which means that any change to them will also be applied to the original df ? and id I do not want this to heppen I need to use '.copy()' ?