# Convert classes to numeric in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I' doing a project based on this Kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings/data and I need to put the data into a kNN model, however this can't be done in its current state as I need to transform the string values into integers.

get_dummies isn't ideal as there are loads of categorical data in the dataset and will create thousands of columns. I am looking for a way to transform strings to numeric representations, for example:

```
Platform || Critic_Score || Publisher || Global_Sales
Wii      ||      73      ||  Nintendo ||  53
Wii      ||      86      ||  Nintendo ||  60
PC       ||      80      ||Activision ||  30
PS3      ||      74      ||Activision ||  35
Xbox360  ||      81      ||   2K      ||  38
```

I'd like to transform into this:

```
Platform || Critic_Score || Publisher || Global_Sales
  1      ||      73      ||     1     ||  53
  1      ||      86      ||     1     ||  60
  2      ||      80      ||     2     ||  30
  3      ||      74      ||     2     ||  35
  4      ||      81      ||     3     ||  38
```

I'm using Python 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Platform'] = pd.factorize(df['Platform'])[0] + 1
df['Publisher'] = pd.factorize(df['Publisher'])[0] + 1
print (df)
   Platform  Critic_Score  Publisher  Global_Sales
0         1            73          1            53
1         1            86          1            60
2         2            80          2            30
3         3            74          2            35
4         4            81          3            38
```

---

```
cols = ['Platform', 'Publisher']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)

print (df)
   Platform  Critic_Score  Publisher  Global_Sales
0         1            73          1            53
1         1            86          1            60
2         2            80          2            30
3         3            74          2            35
4         4            81          3            38
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried this however I get this error message:

C:\Users\Josh Charig\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Also, is the real DF has quite a few columns with text in, is there a wayh to change them all at once?

Comment: Check edited answer. I guess problem is with [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728170/2901002), so need `copy`

Answer (score 7):

You can use Label Encoder [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html]

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['Platform'])
df['Platform']=le.transform(df['Platform'])
le.fit(df['Publisher'])
df['Publisher']=le.transform(df['Publisher'])
print(df)
```

This will give transform strings to numeric representations