# How to select column for a specific time range from pandas dataframe in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

This is my pandas dataframe

```
                     time    energy
0     2018-01-01 00:15:00    0.0000
1     2018-01-01 00:30:00    0.0000
2     2018-01-01 00:45:00    0.0000
3     2018-01-01 01:00:00    0.0000
4     2018-01-01 01:15:00    0.0000
5     2018-01-01 01:30:00    0.0000
6     2018-01-01 01:45:00    0.0000
7     2018-01-01 02:00:00    0.0000
8     2018-01-01 02:15:00    0.0000
9     2018-01-01 02:30:00    0.0000
10    2018-01-01 02:45:00    0.0000
11    2018-01-01 03:00:00    0.0000
12    2018-01-01 03:15:00    0.0000
13    2018-01-01 03:30:00    0.0000
14    2018-01-01 03:45:00    0.0000
15    2018-01-01 04:00:00    0.0000
16    2018-01-01 04:15:00    0.0000
17    2018-01-01 04:30:00    0.0000
18    2018-01-01 04:45:00    0.0000
19    2018-01-01 05:00:00    0.0000
20    2018-01-01 05:15:00    0.0000
21    2018-01-01 05:30:00    0.9392
22    2018-01-01 05:45:00    2.8788
23    2018-01-01 06:00:00    5.5768
24    2018-01-01 06:15:00    8.6660
25    2018-01-01 06:30:00   15.8648
26    2018-01-01 06:45:00   24.1760
27    2018-01-01 07:00:00   38.5324
28    2018-01-01 07:15:00   49.9292
29    2018-01-01 07:30:00   64.3788
```

I would like to select the values from **energy column** using a specific Time range **01:15:00 - 05:30:00** and sum those values. To select datas from column I need both hour and minute values. I know how to select data from column using hour and minute separately..

```
import panadas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
energy_data = pd.read_csv("/home/mayukh/Downloads/Northam_january2018/output1.csv", index_col=None)
#Using Hour 
sum = energy_data[((energy_data.time.dt.hour < 1) & (energy_data.time.dt.hour >= 5))]['energy'].sum()
#using Minute
sum = energy_data[((energy_data.time.dt.minute < 15) & (energy_data.time.dt.minute >= 30))]['energy'].sum()
```

but I don't know how to use both hour and minute together to select data. Please tell me the way how can I will proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) working with `Datetimeindex` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
a = df.set_index('time').between_time('01:15:00','05:30:00')['energy'].sum()
print (a)
0.9392
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.set_index('time').between_time('01:15:00','05:30:00'))
                     energy
time                       
2018-01-01 01:15:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 01:30:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 01:45:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 02:15:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 02:30:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 02:45:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 03:00:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 03:15:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 03:30:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 03:45:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 04:00:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 04:15:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 04:30:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 04:45:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 05:00:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 05:15:00  0.0000
2018-01-01 05:30:00  0.9392
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried using your example before but after compilation I got this error massage   `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  energy_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(energy_data['time'])`

Comment: What is your code before `energy_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(energy_data['time'])` ?

Comment: @Prayuktibid - i think need copy if filtering like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728170/2901002)

Comment: `report_data['energy (kwh)'] = (report_data['actual_generated_energy (kwh)'])
off_peak_energy1 = report_data[report_data.time.dt.weekday >= 5]['energy (kwh)'].sum()
energy = report_data[report_data.time.dt.weekday < 5]`

Comment: so change last row by add `copy` - `energy = report_data[report_data.time.dt.weekday < 5].copy()`

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Comment: @Prayuktibid - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your column to `datetime` and use `.loc` accessor with [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
from datetime import datetime

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

start = datetime.strptime('01:15:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
end = datetime.strptime('05:30:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

result = df.loc[df['A'].dt.time.between(start, end), 'energy'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I can not use date because date is variable for my case the ate could be anything. Actually I want to sum up all the values between **01:15:00 - 05:30:00** for pone month so, in a month the date could be anyrthing but the time range will be fixed for each day.

Comment: @Prayuktibid, see update. This will work independent of date.