# Python Pandas - how to convert string HH:MM:SS.mmm to float sss.ms?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, floating-point-conversion

I would like to convert string value HH:MM:SS.mmm to float value sec.milliseconds for arithmetic calculations. Is there a direct way to do this as currently I am doing it via split string function and it is a very tedious process. Dataframe looks like:

```
Col1
00:00:05.063
00:01:00.728
00:03:10.117
```

Output should look like

```
  5.063
 60.728
190.117
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your column to `timedelta`, and then to `int` (with returns the result in `ns`, divide by `1e9` to get seconds):

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Col1).astype(int) / 1e9

0      5.063
1     60.728
2    190.117
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) + [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['Col1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Col1']).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
      Col1
0    5.063
1   60.728
2  190.117
```

Comment: I tried this and worked very well. Thanks for the prompt response. However, I get the below warning when I run the code  

C:\Users\R15445\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Unfortunately this warning is not show correctly. I guess problem is with filtering - need `copy` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728170/2901002). So what is your code above `df['Col1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Col1']).dt.total_seconds()` ?

Comment: Another possible problem is for set values - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/2901002)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['HourandMinute'] = df['Dayandtime_call'].dt.hour + \
    df['Dayandtime_call'].dt.minute / 100
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: I suppose "Dayandtime_call" should be "Col1" here, given that's how it's displayed in cs95's output.