# Creating new column in Pandas with a condition based on existing row values and returning another row's values

Tags: python, pandas

would like some help with the following problem. 
I currently have a panda dataframe with 3 columns - test1, test2, test3

What I hope to achieve is result in the result_column, where the logic will be:

1) If value in test1 **AND** test2 > 0, then return value of test3

2) Else If value test1 **AND** test2 < 0, then return **NEGATIVE** value of test3

3) Otherwise return 0

```
  test1  test2  test3  result_column
0    0.5    0.1   1.25    1.25
1    0.2   -0.2   0.22       0
2   -0.3   -0.2   1.12   -1.12
3    0.4   -0.3   0.34       0
4    0.5      0   0.45       0
```

This is my first time posting a question on python and pandas. Apologies in advance if the formatting here is not optimum. Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with conditions chained by `&` (`AND`) or select all tested columns by subset `[[]]`, compare ant test by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
m1 = (df.test1 > 0) & (df.test2 > 0)
#alternative
#m1 = (df[['test1', 'test2']] > 0).all(axis=1)

m2 = (df.test1 < 0) & (df.test2 < 0)
#alternative
#m2 = (df[['test1', 'test2']] < 0).all(axis=1)

df['result_column'] = np.select([m1,m2], [df.test3, -df.test3], default=0)
print (df)
   test1  test2  test3  result_column
0    0.5    0.1   1.25           1.25
1    0.2   -0.2   0.22           0.00
2   -0.3   -0.2   1.12          -1.12
3    0.4   -0.3   0.34           0.00
4    0.5    0.0   0.45           0.00
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works well!

it, however, gave a "SettingwithCopyWarning" error though. Although I am still able to run this block. Do I need to worry about this error? 

C:\blp\BQuant\environments\bqnt-0.42.2\lib\site-packages\bqnb\kernelapp.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: I think problem should be another - I guess [need copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728170/2901002) if filter. Or maybe problem with `set values` - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: @Singapore123 - Can you show me code above `df['result_column'] = np.select([m1,m2], [df.test3, -df.test3], default=0)` ?

Comment: I used the one you suggested - 
m1 = (df.test1 > 0) & (df.test2 > 0)
m2 = (df.test1 < 0) & (df.test2 < 0)

and it works well

Answer (score 3):

Clever use of `np.sign` and logic
If both `> 0` or both `< 0` then product is `1`, otherwise product is `-1` or `0`.  If both `> 0` then sign of sum is `1`.  If both `< 0` then sign of sum is `-1`, else `0`.  The product of these things is exactly what we want.

```
v = np.sign(df[['test1', 'test2']].values)
df.assign(result_column=v.prod(1) * np.sign(v.sum(1)) * df.test3 + 0)

   test1  test2  test3  result_column
0    0.5    0.1   1.25           1.25
1    0.2   -0.2   0.22           0.00
2   -0.3   -0.2   1.12          -1.12
3    0.4   -0.3   0.34           0.00
4    0.5    0.0   0.45           0.00
```