# Couldn't read dat file from online source in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I could not read [this *dat* file](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/2002/2002-state-and-county/est02all.dat) in python.

I tried the following :

```
url3 = 'https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/2002/2002-state-and-county/est02all.dat'
import pandas as pd
saipe02 = pd.read_csv(url3, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

Or :

```
import numpy as np
saipe02 = np.fromfile(url3)
```

but they don't work.
Only this code works but I couldn't put any delimiter to separate the data into column. I tried many delimiters, but it doesn't work:

```
saipe02=pd.read_table(url3,header=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html), [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns):

```
saipe02 = pd.read_fwf(url3, header=None)
print (saipe02.head())
   0   1         2         3     ...       30  31            32         33
0   0   0  34569951  33912173    ...      NaN  US  est02ALL.dat  29OCT2004
1   1   0    679856    646828    ...      NaN  AL  est02ALL.dat  29OCT2004
2   1   1      4795      3728    ...      NaN  AL  est02ALL.dat  29OCT2004
3   1   3     16175     12558    ...      NaN  AL  est02ALL.dat  29OCT2004
4   1   5      6152      4767    ...      NaN  AL  est02ALL.dat  29OCT2004

[5 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: thanks very much. I have one more question:     saipe02 = pd.read_fwf(url3, header=None,dtype=object)
medin02=saipe02.iloc[:,[0,1,20]]
medin02.columns = ['state_fips', 'county_fips','med_income_02']
medin02['state_fips']=medin02.loc[:,'state_fips'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>2}'.format(x))
It warns Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
After I changed to this code: medin02['state_fips']=medin02['state_fips'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>2}'.format(x)) It still warns the same thing.

Comment: You need `copy` like `medin02=saipe02.iloc[:,[0,1,20]].copy()`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728170/2901002) for explanation.